# Using regex to find all phrases that are completely capitalized

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I want to use regex to match with all substrings that are completely capitalized, included the spaces.

Right now I am using regexp: `\w*[A-Z]\s]`

HERE IS Test WHAT ARE WE SAYING

Which returns:

```
HERE
IS
WHAT
ARE 
WE
SAYING
```

However, I would like it to match with all substrings that are allcaps, so that it returns:

```
HERE IS 
WHAT ARE WE SAYING
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use word boundaries `\b` and `[^\s]` to prevent starting and ending spaces. Put together it might look a little like:

```
import re
string = "HERE IS Test WHAT ARE WE SAYING is that OKAY"

matches = re.compile(r"\b[^\s][A-Z\s]+[^\s]\b")
matches.findall(string)

>>> ['HERE IS', 'WHAT ARE WE SAYING', 'OKAY']
```

Comment: Oh jeez -- head in JS code. Thanks @DanielMesejo. Fixed

Comment: `\b[^\s][A-Z\s]+[^\s]\b` will match words like `aBc` and miss short words, like `WE` if surrounded by non-capitalized words. The test string `A ab ABC ABC abc Abc aBc abC C` will output `['ABC ABC', 'aBc']`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `re.split` with the pattern `\s*(?:\w*[^A-Z\s]\w*\s*)+`:

```
input = "HERE IS Test WHAT ARE WE SAYING"
parts = re.split('\s*(?:\w*[^A-Z\s]\w*\s*)+', input)
print(parts);

['HERE IS', 'WHAT ARE WE SAYING']
```

The idea here is to split on any sequential cluster of words which contains one or more letter which is *not* uppercase.

Comment: @DanielMesejo It is now :-)  ... don't know why, but I thought I saw PHP.  I am on a cell phone at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re

text = 'HERE IS Test WHAT ARE WE SAYING'
print(re.findall('[\sA-Z]+(?![a-z])', text))
```

**Output**

```
['HERE IS ', ' WHAT ARE WE SAYING']
```

The pattern `[\sA-Z]+(?![a-z])` matches any space or capitalized letter, that is not followed by a non-capitalized letter. The notation `(?![a-z])` is known as a negative lookahead (see [Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[A-Z ]+` to match capital letters and spaces, and use negative lookahead `(?! )` and negative lookbehind `(?<! )` to forbid the first and last character from being a space.

Finally, surrounding the pattern with `\b` to match word boundaries will make it only match full words.

```
import re
text = "A ab ABC ABC abc Abc aBc abC C"
pattern = r'\b(?! )[A-Z ]+(?<! )\b'

re.findall(pattern, text)
>>> ['A', 'ABC ABC', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following method:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'HERE IS Test WHAT ARE WE SAYING'
>>> print(re.findall('((?!\s+)[A-Z\s]+(?![a-z]+))', s))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['HERE IS ', 'WHAT ARE WE SAYING']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using findall() without matching leading and trailing spaces:

```
re.findall(r"\b[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*\b",s)                                                                            
Out: ['HERE IS', 'WHAT ARE WE SAYING']
```